# RxJava1: How to convert Observable<List<Observable<X>>> to Observable<List<X>>

Tags: rx-java, rx-kotlin

Can someone help me find the proper solution for this problem I face?

1. I have a backend service that give me `Observables` of the data I need, which are `Events`.
2. Form the Event I can get an `EventGroup`, which contains Ids of all events in the same group.
3. Next I can get all the `Event`s that are part of this group.

However, I get a `Observable<List<Observable<Event>>>`, where I'd like to get a `Observable<List<Event>>`. How can I achive this, without actually subscribing to the nested `Observables`?

```
val events : Observable<List<Observable<Event>>> = 
   eventProvider.observable
      .flatMap { myBackend.getEventGroup(it.eventGroupId) }
      .map { 
         it.eventIds.map { myBackend.getEvent(it) } 
      }
```

**TL:DR**

How do I get `Observable<List<X>>` from a `Observable<List<Observable<X>>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, inspired by the answer of @akarnokd. @akarnokd answer expects all sources to be finite, but mine are all infinite. However I can live with partially infinite as well.

I need my resulting `Observable` to be infinite, because I want to receive a new list of `Events` whenever the `eventProvider.observable` emits something. However, I'm ok with the events I get back via `myBackend.getEvent(it)` to behave as a finite source.

```
val events : Observable<List<Event>> = 
   eventProvider.observable
      .flatMap { myBackend.getEventGroup(it.eventGroupId) }
      .map { it.eventIds.map { myBackend.getEvent(it) } }
      .map { it.toObservable().flatMap { it.first() }.toList() }
      .flatMap { it }
```

Answer (score 1):

flatMap twice and then use toList:

```
Observable<List<Observable<X>> source = ...

Observable<Observable<X>> step1 = source.flatMapIterable(v -> v);

Observable<X> step2 = step1.flatMap(v -> v);

Observable<List<X>> result = step2.toList();
```

Note that this requires all participating Observables to be finite.

Comment: All the `Observables` are infinite, so I cannot directly use your approach. However, your answer did lead me to the direction I needed, because I could convert on of the `Observables` into a finite one. Thanks :)